# WebExtension - how to send context menu selectionText to popup action?

Tags: chrome-extension-manifest-v3, web-extension

I'm trying to get a context menu webextension working which sends the selected text to the popup/action page of the extension, using message passing.

(I know I could display the selection into the page tab using `executeScript` with something like an `alert()`, but I want it to be sent and displayed in the extension's action popup).

I have the following code:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Selected text to popup action",
  "short_name": "context-to-popup",
  "description": "Attempt to send context menu selected text to extension popup action page",
  "version": "0.1",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "88",
  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "scripting"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
  // in Chrome, instead of "background"-> "scripts", use: "background": {"service_worker": "background.js"}
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="action.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='result-div' style="width:500px">
    <h4>Selected text is: </h4>
    <code id='result'></code>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**action.js**

```
// https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log("running onmessage listener..");
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script: " + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
    var resp = request.msg;
    if (resp) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerText = resp;
        sendResponse({farewell: "thank you for sending!! goodbye"});
    }
  }
);
```

**background.js**

```
passSelection = function(info, tab) {
    console.log("selection: ", info.selectionText);
    
    // outside of executeScript
    /*(async () => {
        const response = await chrome.runtime.sendMessage({msg: info.selectionText});
        // do something with response here, not outside the function
        console.log(response);
    });*/
    
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: tab.id },
        func: () => {
            (async () => {
                const response = await chrome.runtime.sendMessage({msg: info.selectionText});
                // do something with response here, not outside the function
                console.log(response);
            });
        }
    });
    
    // now open the popup
    chrome.action.openPopup();
};

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        id: "selection-to-ext",
        title: "send selection to extension",
        contexts: ["selection"]
    });
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(passSelection);
```

This prints the selection to the extension console but doesn't send the selected text to the action and doesn't output any errors in the tab or extension console. Tested in both Firefox and Chromium.

Similar messaging code from https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/ is working when I pass something from the tab document DOM

Does anybody know how to do this or why this doesn't work with context menu selectionText ?

Comment: The popup can't receive messages if it's not shown and you can't use openPopup in the stable Chrome yet as it's not allowed. If you use a dev channel or Canary the problem is that opening the popup takes time so it won't be open when you send the message yet. Instead of using messages and executeScript you can store and read the text using chrome.storage.session.